# apply custom discount in cart magento2 via observer

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, sales, promotions

I have created a custom promotion in magento2. To get that working I needed to do some customization in cart which I am trying to do with **`salesrule_validator_process`** event.
I needed the **rulename and discount values** to be modified before applying in cart.

Now In Magento1 we used to update values as below:

> $result = $observer['result'];
>
> $result->setDiscountAmount($DiscountAmount);
>
> $result->setBaseDiscountAmount($BaseDiscountAmount);

How we can achieve the same in Magento2?

Any thoughts/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you get any solution..

Answer (score 1):

You can apply discount amount in magento2 by same event just write below code in your observer file:

```
$result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();

$result->setAmount($DiscountAmoun);

$result->setBaseAmount($DiscountAmoun);
```

Comment: It is not working. I already tried.

Comment: This event dispatch from
  vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/RulesApplier.php
  eventFix()  and it will call when anybody apply coupon code from cart page

Comment: Yes I know that. How i can use this info for setting new dicsount? Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: from where you want get access your discount? you can get  any model factory or collection factory by just pass it from construct function and put your logic before apply set amount.

Comment: I tried this.
$result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();

$result->setAmount(10);

$result->setBaseAmount(10);
but this is not working.

Comment: any solution? I am facing same issue.